# Powerbuilder 9.0 application crashes on Windows Server 2008

Tags: powerbuilder, sybase-ase15

Powerbuilder application on server crashes whenever we try to disconnect the database profile using database painter. We are using SYC Sybase ASE Database profile. Following are the problem details:

Problem signature:

- Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
- Application Name:     pb90.exe
- Application Version:  9.0.0.5507
- Application Timestamp: 3e51cadc
- Fault Module Name:   ntdll.dll
- Fault Module Version:    6.1.7601.18798
- Fault Module Timestamp:  5507b3e0
- Exception Code:  c0000005
- Exception Offset:    00032a04
- OS Version:  6.1.7601.2.1.0.274.10
- Locale ID:   2057
- Additional Information 1:    ca29
- Additional Information 2:    ca297e53a7bc8ecbda8afbd7a6da98af
- Additional Information 3:    0917
- Additional Information 4:    09170061222965cddc531651cd06f2bc

Read our privacy statement online:
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0409

If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our privacy statement offline:
  C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt

Can anyone please advice on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dll's of ASE-15.0 were causing powerbuilder application to crash. After reinstalling ASE-15.0 on Server, our powerbuilder 9.0 application started working normally.

Answer (score 0):

Running the PB IDE on Windows Server 2008 is not supported.  It's supported as a RUNTIME platform only, for 12.5.1 or higher.

You'll need to upgrade from 9.0 and use a different platform as your workstation.

-Paul-